# Matplotlib does not show up on ubuntu windows subsystem

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, matplotlib, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed matplotlib on ubuntu windows subsystem and run this simple code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.show()
```

But it just does not show up anything.

So I tryied to install matplotlib on windows powershell and then executed the same code and it worked well:

[image]

Well even know it worked fine using powershell I really want to run my programs using linux susbystem, what should I do?

Comment: AFAIK, Ubuntu subsystem does not support graphical engine. Your option can be either installing dual OS on your computer or running a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

WSL does not support graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup X server for WSL.
Have a look at https://x410.dev/